# What could be the value of p if it was an event?

Tags: probability

please help me.

I've been stuck on a problem that says, "Supposed an event has a probability of *p*. What can you say about the value of *p*? What is the probability that the event will not occur? Explain. I do not understand what the problem is asking *or* what *p* could be...

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you what rules you know about probabilities. That is, can $p$ be any real number? If I have a fair six-sided die, I can colour half the sides red so that when you roll it, you get a red side with probability $p=\frac{1}{2}$. But no matter how I colour the faces, I can't make it so that when you roll it, you get a red side with probability $p=\frac{45}{2}$ - the rules of probability don't allow that.

1. What's the highest probability I can get?
2. What's the lowest probability I can get?
3. For a fair six-sided die, I can only get probabilities which are a multiple of $\frac{1}{6}$. If I change the problem (e.g. I use a biased coin), am I able to get every probability between the minimum and the maximum?

The second half of the question saying the following:

> Suppose I have a biased coin which always lands either heads or tails, and which lands heads with probability $p$. What's the probability it lands tails?